# can't reach vagrant box over private network

Tags: macos, centos, vagrant, virtualbox, osx-elcapitan

My vagrant box stop working for unknown reason and even if a reinstall all the box trough my ansible script, it don't want to be reached by http://192.168.33.10/.

here my vagrant file :

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos67vm"

  config.vm.synced_folder "../../pjt" , "/var/www/pjt", owner: "pjt", group: "pjt", mount_options: ["dmode=777,fmode=777"]
  config.vm.synced_folder "../../library" , "/var/library"

  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "ansible.sh"

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.name = "dev-pjt"
  end

end
```

when i ping the ip i got :

```
ping 192.168.33.10
PING 192.168.33.10 (192.168.33.10): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
^C
--- 192.168.33.10 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

the ifconfig in the box give me that :

```
ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:1B:2F:CC
          inet adr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
          adr inet6: fe80::a00:27ff:fe1b:2fcc/64 Scope:Lien
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:967 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:635 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000
          RX bytes:100532 (98.1 KiB)  TX bytes:85600 (83.5 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:2A:FE:79
          inet adr:192.168.33.10  Bcast:192.168.33.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
          adr inet6: fe80::a00:27ff:fe2a:fe79/64 Scope:Lien
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:27 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:1974 (1.9 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Boucle locale
          inet adr:127.0.0.1  Masque:255.0.0.0
          adr inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Hôte
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

i'm don't know where do i need to dig in to find a solution (my mac or virtualbox ?) , hope somebody can help me.

Comment: already tried that @FrédéricHenri , even with a "sudo service iptables stop" i'm not able to ping the box.

Comment: When i do a traceroute 192.168.33.10, it go outside on the web and don't stay in the mac :/

Comment: are you on corporate network ? is there an existing subdomain on 192.168 ?

Comment: yes corporate network but no subdomain with 192.168 @FrédéricHenri. Can you explain to me the reasons it stop working, i mean, where do i need to look to try to find a clue.

Answer (score 1):

Finally resolve the problem...  but don't know how... so here the steps that i did :

- sudo route -n flush
- rebooted the macbook
- deactivated little snitch and nod32 antivirus
- vagrant up
- successfully ping and go to http://192.168.33.10/
- vagrant halt
- reactivated little snitch and nod32 antivirus
- vagrant up
- successfully ping and go to http://192.168.33.10/

i don't know if it's the "sudo route -n flush" or the reboot that made the connection work again.

hope it will help somebody ;)

Comment: For me, just restarting my mac solved the issue